# React-select with React-hook-form , focus on error problem

Tags: validation, controller, react-select, react-hook-form

I'm trying to validate a form.
The problem arises when I insert a React-select component into a controller: even if the rules are set to "required: true", if there is another normal input box error after the Controller, it jumps to the next one and loses focus on the controller error (in this case the "Brand commented section").
Here the code:

```js
export default function Proof() {
    const { register, handleSubmit, errors, control } = useForm();
    const refReactSelect = useRef();

    const createHandler = (data) => {
        console.log(data);
    }
    return (
        <div>
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(createHandler)}>
                <label className="font-weight-medium" htmlFor="productCategory">Category</label>
                {/* Name */}
                <div className="form-group pb-2">
                    <label className="font-weight-medium" htmlFor="productName">Name</label>
                    <input
                        className="form-control"
                        type="name"
                        id="productName"
                        name="productName"
                        ref={register({ required: true })}
                    />
                    {errors.productName && errors.productName.type === "required" && (
                        <p className="text-danger">{"Empty name"}</p>
                    )}
                </div>

                <Controller
                    name="productCategory"
                    as={
                        <Select
                            ref={refReactSelect}
                            options={categories}
                            isSearchable={true}
                            placeholder="Select"
                            id="productCategory" />
                    }
                    control={control}
                    rules={{ required: true }}
                />
                {errors.productCategory && errors.productCategory.type === "required" && (
                    <p className="text-danger">{"Empty category"}</p>
                )}

                {/* Brand */}
                <div className="form-group pb-2">
                    <label className="font-weight-medium" htmlFor="productBrand">Brand</label>
                    <input
                        className="form-control"
                        type="text"
                        id="productBrand"
                        name="productBrand"
                        // onChange={(e) => setBrand(e.target.value)}
                        ref={register({ required: true })}
                    />
                    {errors.productBrand && errors.productBrand.type === "required" && (
                        <p className="text-danger">{"Empty Brand"}</p>
                    )}
                </div>

                <div>
                    <button type="submit">Click here </button>
                </div>
            </form>

        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: Any solutions??

Comment: I've come across the same problem. Any ideas would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I also came across this kind of scenario. So, you can create a function as `onError`, which will scroll to that field in case of any error.

```
const onError= () => window.scrollTo(0, inputErrorRef.current?.offsetTop || 0)
```

Inside the controller, for `onFocus` event, you can call this `onError` function.
Also, pass a ref to the error message `<p>` tag. So whenever we are having an error, the element will be present in dom and we can refer it by `ref`

```
 <Controller
  name="productCategory"
   onFocus={onError}
  as={
    <Select
      ref={refReactSelect}
      options={categories}
      isSearchable={true}
      placeholder="Select"
      id="productCategory"
    />
  }
  control={control}
  rules={{ required: true }}
/>;
{
  errors.productCategory && errors.productCategory.type === "required" && (
    <p ref={errorRef} className="text-danger">{"Empty category"}</p>
  );
}
```

Can you try this once ? and let me know if it helps!

Answer (score 1):

Encountered similar issue and came across a [reply](https://github.com/react-hook-form/react-hook-form/issues/6432#issuecomment-911436170) from RHF's maintainer in their issue tracker:

> This is due to the registration order with register API, the controller's >register will always going to be behind the native input's registration, if >the focus order is important, consider move everything into Controller or ?>register only.

So basically what we need to do is to register all the fields with register method returned by useForm only or solely utilize the Controller component.

This is a working example based on the code you post:
[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/empty-water-jfds8n?file=/src/Proof.jsx)

Since I'm using the latest version, the RHF api might be a little different. However, this should not be a concern since the root cause of our problem remains the same - the registration order of the fields.